# UITextfield letting only one decimal

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How to let user insert only one decimal in the textfield in language Swift.There are quite a lot of help for this on the site,but none of them work as they are all Swift 1 code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show Swift-1 code that you tried, and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make your class conform the to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Then, you should set the delegate of your textField to self:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Finally, whenever the content of your `UITextField` changes, this delegate method will be called, so add it to your view controller.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   //handle changes here

}
```

If you want only one character to appear you could disallow changes to the content of your `UITextField` when it is already filled:

```
if yourTextField.text?.characters.count > 0 {

       return false

    }

    return true
```

If you only want to allow decimal characters you could check for this too, and add the condition to the if query.

Comment: Thank you mate, really appreciate it.